# Scope of an outer function variable?

Tags: python, function, scope

I am confused by the scope of the outer function variable with respect to the inner function in Python.

It seems that if a variable in the outer function is a list or array, it can be changed by the inner function while it can not if it is a scalar. For example, the following code gives an output of c = [0,-10].

```
def foo1():
    a = [0,1]

    def foo2():
        a[1] = -10

    foo2()
    return a


c = foo1()
```

Whereas the following code gives c = 1.

```
def foo1():
    a = 1

    def foo2():
        a = -10

    foo2()
    return a


c = foo1()
```

Why should there be a difference with respect to the type of the variable? Does this have to do with pointers?

Comment: Assignment to a variable makes it local by default; your second example would need `nonlocal a` in `foo2()` to actually refer to the outer function's variable.  But `a[1] = -10` isn't an assignment to `a`, it's a mutation of it, so the outer variable is being referenced.

Comment: Note, *variables don't have types*. The type of *the object being referenced* by the variable is *irrelevant*. Use `a = [0, 1]` then in the inner function do `a = [-10, 1]` and you'll see the same bevahior. In the first case, you are *mutating* the object with a local reference, in the second case, you are *assign a value to a new, local variable*. Two totally different things. I suggest reading the following: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first example, "a" is passed in as a parameter, therefore you are able to access or change it as normal. In the second example, any changes to "a" stay saved only within the inner function. To fix this you can make "a" global:

```
def foo1():
    a = 1

    def foo2():
        global a
        a = -10

    foo2()
    return a


c = foo1()
```

Comment: this does not act as expected, here, you would want `nonlocal`.... otherwise this still returns `1` to `c`

Answer (score 1):

It doesnt have anything to do with pointers, its how lists are used, when you do list[1] = x, this is a member assignment, which is actually a “method call”. Basically when ur changing the value of a member in a list, its doing a method call, that can find the name of the list in the global name space.